# Kerboros authentication sample code required

Tags: linux, kerberos

I wanted to implement Kerboros login for a LINUX based server. Can anyone provide a sample for the implementation with test credentials.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad currently.  What type of web server, HTTPD?  What type of Kerberos - MIT Kerberos, Kerberos with Active Directory?

Comment: webserver: apache-httpd, kerboros with active directory.

Comment: Sorry for being short, I am very new to this.

Comment: can you anybody suggest please..i dont see an easily understandable documents online. Thanks!